# Spark Dataset reading a CSV with a missing column

Tags: java, apache-spark

Assume i have

```
public class A {
    int    field1;
    String field2;
    double field3;
    int    field4;

// getters and setters
}
```

However, I have CSV files that only have

```
field1,field2,field3
field1,field2,field3
field1,field2,field3
...
```

How do i get spark to read the CSV and convert to bean A without complaining about missing field4 ?

```
sqlContext
     .read()
     .schema(schema)
     .csv(inputFile)
     .as(Encoders.bean(A.class));
```

It complains about

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`field4`' given input columns: [field1, field2, field3];
```

I tried adding in

```
sqlContext
     .read()
     .schema(schema)
     .csv(inputFile)
     .withColumn("field4", lit(1))
     .as(Encoders.bean(A.class));
```

but that then complains about

```
2020/01/29 09:15:19 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.lang.NullPointerException: Null value appeared in non-nullable field:
currently no type path record in java
If the schema is inferred from a Scala tuple/case class, or a Java bean, please try to use scala.Option[_] or other nullable types (e.g. java.lang.Integer instead of int/scala.Int).
```

Comment: Have you tried to define schema externally, as in `read().csv(input-file).schema(four-field-schema).option("enforceSchema","false")`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an issue with the way you are creating `schema` that you are supplying.

Please refer below code snippet to see if it works for you.

```
String inputFile = "/tmp/person01.csv";
        StructField[] structFieldsFirst = new StructField[4];
        structFieldsFirst[0] = new StructField("field1", DataTypes.IntegerType, true, Metadata.empty());
        structFieldsFirst[1] = new StructField("field2", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty());
        structFieldsFirst[2] = new StructField("field3", DataTypes.DoubleType, true, Metadata.empty());
        structFieldsFirst[3] = new StructField("field4", DataTypes.IntegerType, true, Metadata.empty());
        StructType schema = new StructType(structFieldsFirst);
        Dataset<Person> person = spark.read().schema(schema).csv(inputFile)
         .as(Encoders.bean(Person.class));

        person.show(10, false);
```

Person Class is same as you have mentioned:

```
public class Person {

    int    field1;
    String field2;
    double field3;
    int    field4;

}
```

Input is:

```
1,field2,4
2,field2,5
3,field2,6
```

This piece of code is returning following output:

```
+------+------+------+------+
|field1|field2|field3|field4|
+------+------+------+------+
|1     |field2|4.0   |null  |
|2     |field2|5.0   |null  |
|3     |field2|6.0   |null  |
+------+------+------+------+
```

Comment: Figured it out - The missing value in the file was being handled ok, but a NULL value in a field in the file wasn't. So although the schema said the field was nullable, the Encoder would fail trying to set a primitive to null and hence the NPE. Had to change all nullable primitive fields to their boxed counterparts